# pytest's html reporter doesn't take/show screenshot in the test reports for pytest-playwright based tests

Tags: pytest, playwright-python

I tried to run my first playwright test using `pytest-playwright` and the test runs fine but when I tried to use the pytest `html reporter` to show me the report with a screenshot for a failed test it doesn't work

pytest version == `7.0.1`
pytest-playwright version == `0.2.3`

Test which is expected to fail:

```
    def test_pw():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto("http://www.html")
        browser.close()
```

[image: test report without any screenshot for failed test]

Run command: `pytest --html report_pw1.html`

Can anyone please suggest what am i missing here?
I read the [docs](https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for pytest html and it says that a screenshot should automatically be included by default for failed tests but its not happening so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create **conftest.py** file at the root level. I adapted this code from pytest-html official documentation:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("html")
    outcome = yield
    screen_file = ''
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, "extra", [])
    if report.when == "call":
        if report.failed and "page" in item.funcargs:
            page = item.funcargs["page"]
            screenshot_dir = Path("screenshots")
            screenshot_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
            screen_file = str(screenshot_dir / f"{slugify(item.nodeid)}.png")
            page.screenshot(path=screen_file)
        xfail = hasattr(report, "wasxfail")
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            # add the screenshots to the html report
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.png(screen_file))
        report.extra = extra
```

You have to install pytest-playwright:

```
pip install pytest-playwright
```

Then your tests have access to the **page** fixture (and it is available for **item.funcargs** in the conftest.py file):

```
def test_example_is_failing(page):
    page.goto("https://example.com")
    assert page.inner_text('h1') == 'Any text to make it fail'
```

I am sure there should be a better way if we dig more in the documentation. I used these links:

- Pytest-html documentation for extra content:

  https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#extra-content
- Playwright pytest plugin:

  https://playwright.dev/python/docs/test-runners

Answer (score 0):

If you meant plugin [pytest-html-reporter](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html-reporter/) (**not** [pytest-html](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/)) then below implementation for capturing screenshot might help

*Note: driver initialisation needs to be done in a method name `setup` in conftest.py using a pytest fixture*

```
from pytest_html_reporter import attach
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class BaseClass:
    pass

class TestClass(BaseClass):

    def test_pass(self):
        assert True

    def test_fail(self):
        assert False


    def teardown_method(self):
        '''to capture screenshot on test method failure'''
        attach(data=self.driver.get_screenshot_as_png())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the accepted answer using pytest-html and conftest.py file worked for me